# Creating a simple custom apt-get/config script

Tags: ubuntu, bash, script, apt-get

As I play more and more with Ubuntu, I'm starting to see how I can automate the majority of the repetitive commands that I perform whenever I reinstall the operating system. Thus far, it's just one **gigantic** apt-get script/terminal command list that's connected by dozens of && symbols.

I used to be decent at python, but I've forgotten quite a lot. Here's what my apt-get command looks like right now (which I simply paste in and press enter):

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:numix/ppa && sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/hexchat-stable && sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/nemo && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y numix-icon-theme numix-gtk-theme docky hexchat nemo nemo-fileroller dconf-tools vlc unity-tweak-tool gnome-tweak-tool python-pip && sudo pip install speedtest-cli && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false && xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Numix" && gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Numix-Circle' && gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
```

I know, it's not exactly clean. I don't want to keep doing it this way and I'd like to turn it into a script of sorts that would be far easier for me to update, maintain, and read. Here's some pseudo code I typed up of what I'd like to do.

```
#Install/Config Script

#Add Repos
print ("Adding Numix, Hexchat, and Webupd8 Repositories...")
enter.line ('sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:numix/ppa && sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/hexchat-stable && sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/nemo')

#Update Repos
print ("Updating repostiory lists...")
enter.line ('sudo apt-get update')

#Install apps
print ("Installing Numix Icon Theme...")
enter.line ('sudo apt-get install -y numix-icon-theme')
print ("Installing etc etc...")

#Configure Nemo File Explorer
print ("Configuring Nemo as default file manager")
enter.line ('gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons false')
enter.line ('xdg-mime default nemo.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search')

#Set Numix Theme and fix scrollbars
print ("Setting Numix GTK and Icon Set...")
enter.line ('gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Numix"')
enter.line ('gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme 'Numix-Circle'')
enter.line ('gsettings set com.canonical.desktop.interface scrollbar-mode normal
')
```

Essentially, I'd like to be able to save it as some sort of executable script, and simply run it in the terminal and let it do its thing. I'm familiar with Java, C++, and Python, but it has been a long time since I have coded.

Any suggestions for someone trying to get back into the game would be much appreciated! **Please note I am not asking for anyone to do all the work for me. I'm looking forward to trying and failing as I figure it out on my own, I'd just love for some input on how to start, what language to use, organizational layouts, and any other helpful tips for getting started.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a shell script (bash):

```
#!/bin/bash
#above line ensures it runs with bash because of the '#!'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y numix-icon-theme package2 package3 package4
sudo apt-get install -y package5 package6 package7 etc

gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme "Numix"
```

Alternatively, if you know your preferences will change, you could write a script that reads in an input file:

```
#newserver.in
install,numix-icon-theme,package2,package3
install,package4
custom,gsettings,"set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme \"Numix\""
```

### Reading an input file

```
#!/bin/bash
infile=foobar.in
thisserver=""

cat $infile | while read line
do
   case $line in
      "#"*) [ ];; #matches commented lines
      "") [ ]  ;; #matches empty lines
      *)          #matches the rest
         #echo $line 
         while IFS=, read val1 val2 val3 val4 val5 val6
         do
            #echo "val1=$val1   val2=$val2   val3=$val3   val4=$val4"
            #echo "$thisserver    $line"
            if [[ "$thisserver" == author* ]] && [ "$val1" != "SERVER" ];
            then
               echo "$val1 $val2 wrote during the $val3"
            elif [[ "$thisserver" == movies* ]] && [ "$val1" != "SERVER" ];
            then
               echo "$val1 ($val2) rates $val3 on imdb.com"
            fi
            if [ "$val1" = "SERVER" ];
            then
               echo "$val2"
               thisserver=$val2
            fi

         done <<< $line
         ;;
   esac

done
```

#### foobar.in

```
#foobar.in

# example comment
SERVER,authors.example.com,
alexandre,dumas,1700s
robert,heinlein,1900s,science fiction, nothing to see here, extra properties

timothy,zahn,1900s,
mark,twain,1800s,
SERVER,movies.example.com,
The Avengers,2012,8,
Star Wars,1997,9,
Ratatouille,2007,8,
```

Comment: Many scripts that I write read in files. If you want me to summarize in this answer, I can.

Comment: If you could, that would be wonderful! It would make it a lot easier to simply add a new package whenever I need to update the script.

Comment: Ping. I added "Reading an input file."

Comment: I apologize for the late reply. This is great~ I'm playing around with it now and I'm looking forward to getting it working.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just save that line in a file called, say, `do_stuff.sh`.  And run it like this `. path/to/do_stuff.sh`.

If you really want to do it properly just add `#!/bin/bash` as a first line and `chmod +x path/to/do_stuff.sh`.  Then you can run it as an executable.

No need to (re)learn python - bash *is* a scripting language.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't realize bash scripting was that easy.

Comment: How do bash scripts know to execute the next line when the first line has finished? I know that ; means to execute regardless of the preceding command whereas && will only execute if the preceding command was successful. So which does bash pick by default?

Comment: newline is equivalent to a semi-colon